# Combine Navigation drawer, fragments and arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity

I have an app that uses navigation drawer, five fragments that each shows a Listview filled with some text.

It looks quite awful and messy so now i'm trying to come up with something a little bit cleaner and uses sections. I came a cross a app which seems to use an ArrayAdapter + ListActivity so i thought i give it a shot and include something similar in my app.

Though I'm getting an error when implementing it.

This is how my MainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mFragmentTitles;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mFragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fragments);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mFragmentTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); //need  import android.app.ActionBar;
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#002d55"));     
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
    mDrawerLayout, 
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
    R.string.drawer_open, 
    R.string.drawer_close 
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}


private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment_1();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        newFragment = new Fragment_1();
        break;
    case 1:
        newFragment = new Fragment_2();
        break;
    case 2:
        newFragment = new Fragment_3();
        break;
    case 3:
        newFragment = new Fragment_4();
        break;
    case 4:
        newFragment = new Fragment_5();
        break;

    }
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
    .commit();


    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mFragmentTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

But I'm getting error on these places that says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment_1 to Fragment":

Fragment newFragment = **new Fragment_1();**

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

switch(position){

case 0:

newFragment = ** new Fragment_1();**

break;

Here's my Fragment_1:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_1);

    LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Header(i, "Januari"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Vasalunds IF" , "Skytteholms IP, 19/1 18:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Molde FK" , "La Manga, 27/1 16:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Rosenborg BK", "La Manga, 30/1 16:00"));

    items.add(new Header(i, "Februari"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "FC Astra" , "La Manga, 2/2 19:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "FC Costuleni", "Pinatar Arena, 5/2 16:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "IF Elfsborg", "Skytteholms IP, 15/2 13:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Liaoning Whowin FC" , "Shenzhen, 23/2 15:00"));

    items.add(new Header(i, "Mars"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Shenzhen Ruby FC" , "Shenzhen, 1/3 13:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Guangzhou R&F FC", "Shenzhen, 1/3 15:30"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "HJK Helsingfors", "Skytteholms IP, 16/3 13:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Kalmar FF" , "Skytteholms IP, 22/3 15:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "IFK Göteborg" , "Nationalarenan, 31/3 19:00"));

    items.add(new Header(i, "April"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Gefle IF" , "Strömvallen, 6/4 15:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Örebro SK" , "Nationalarenan, 13/4 15:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Dif", "Tele2 Arena, 16/4 19:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "IFK Norrköping" , "Nationalarenan, 20/4 17:30"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "BK Häcken" , "Gamla Ullevi, 27/4 17:30"));

    items.add(new Header(i, "Maj"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Helsingborgs IF" , "Nationalarenan, 5/5 19:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Halmstads BK" , "Örjans Vall, 8/5 19:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Mjällby AIF", "Nationalarenan, 11/5 15:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "IF Elfsborg" , "Nationalarenan, 15/5 19:00"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "Malmö FF" , "Swedbank Stadion, 26/5 19:00"));

    items.add(new Header(i, "Juni"));
    items.add(new EventItem(i, "IF Brommapojkarna" , "Nationalarenan, 2/6 19:00"));

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and fragment_1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragment_1" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `Fragment_1` object to a variable of type `Fragment`. The problem is that `Fragment_1` inherits from `ListActivity`, not from `Fragment`.

Consider changing from using `ListActivity` to using a `ListFragment`.

Comment: Yeah! I've tried that! But then I'm getting error on the following lines in Fragment_1.java. **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)**, **setContentView** and MyListAdapter adapter = **new MyListAdapter(this, items);**

Comment: You'll have to make sure you're using the right functions. In this case `Fragment`s don't have a `setContentView` function. You'll have to inflate or provide a view in the 'onCreateView' callback.

Comment: Hm okay. So how do you purpose I set this up?

Comment: Go over the documentation for `Fragment`s (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html ) and `ListFragment` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html ). It should be clear how to provide a layout for a fragment. Note that a `ListFragment` has a default layout and you only need to provide your own if you want something custom.